# Erro NullPointerException em setMyLocationEnabled()

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, geolocalização

Estou desenvolvendo um app que tem como principal função capturar a localização do usuário. Já fiz um código porém ele da erro, não sei se está completo, fiz seguindo exemplos da internet:

Código:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


}
```

Erro em tempo de execução:

```
Process: com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.navigationdrawervideotutorial, PID: 16457
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
       at br.com.projeto.caminhossembarreiras.MainFragment.onMapReady(MainFragment.java:37)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzl$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.v$a$a.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:82)
       at maps.ei.bu$6.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Erro na linha:

```
 mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

Answer (score 0):

O método `onMapReady` retorna o mapa carregado como parâmetro (`googleMap`).

Você precisa passar a referência para o `mMap`!

Tente o seguinte:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap  = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```